# Check for user login status in php when he tries to submit or vote something?

Tags: php, authentication, status

I have a voting button on my index page for my posts. Now suppose a visitor(which is not logged in) likes a story and clicks for an 'up vote'he gets a notification or alert that he has to login first. Or if he is already logged in, he can vote the stories without any worries.

Can anyone help me in this case? Answers should be relative to php language.

Comment: Do you already have a database setup to keep track of your users?

Comment: Can you post what code you have? Or are you wanting someone to write it all for you?

Comment: @Catfish yes i have a complete database to track the users

Comment: @jostster I just want the code that when he clicks on that vote button he gets the user login status and in it is false generates a jquery notification to login.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a session Boolean variable that indicates whether the user is logged in or not and check it's value at the time of submission.